# Spring. Выдернуть url в string

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

Возможно ли осуществить в спринге такое, что я допустим обращаюсь по url `localhost:8080/myproject/request/123/123/123/123.txt`
и после слова request выдернуть вот эту строку в string? `/123/123/123/123.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping("/request/{path:.*}")
public void handle(@PathVariable String path) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: И в `path` как раз будет желаемая строка.

Comment: Как то не сработало, после первого встречного слэша уже не читает и говорит что страница не найдена

Comment: Странно, должно работать. Ну, тогда остаётся только использовать `@RequestMapping("/request/**")`, а в обработчике разбирать то, что вернёт `getRequestURI`.

Comment: ну примерно это и помогло